# Debug Android configuration stoped working all of a sudden

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, visual-studio-code

***Issue:*** Debug Android configuration failing with error as below

***Description:*** The react native project, I'm working on, runs fine using `react-native run-ios` or `react-native run-android` command.
But with extensions installed, VSCode doesn't debug anymore which it did before. In VSCode, *OUTPUT CONSOLE* shows following error when fails.

***Error:***

> [Error] Error: Unknown error: not all success patterns were matched.
>   It means that "react-native run-android" command failed. Please, check the View -> Toggle Output -> React Native, View -> Toggle Output -> React Native: Run android output windows.

There is a similar issue found at [vscode-react-native repo here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/624), but that issue is still open.